# Adding attributes to a dojo tree node on creation

Tags: tree, dojo, treenode

I'm using a `dojox.data.QueryReadStore` to populate a `dijit.Tree` dynamically on expansion of each node.  When each of the child `TreeNode`s is created, I'd like to put a custom attribute on it.

How do I get called back on the automatic creation of `TreeNode`s before rendering?

Answer (score 2):

Currently it calls _createTreeNode() to create each TreeNode, so you can just connect to that

```
<div dojoType=dijit.Tree ...>
    <script type="dojo/connect" event="_createTreeNode"> ... </script>
...
```

If you want to do something fancier, you could customize the TreeNode class:

```
dojo.declare("MyTreeNode", dijit._TreeNode, { ... })
```

and then make a custom Tree class that uses it:

```
dojo.declare("MyTree", dijit._Tree, {
    _createTreeNode: function(/*Object*/ args){
          return new MyTreeNode(args);
    }
});
```

Comment: The `_createTreeNode` function was removed after 1.7.

Comment: I still see it in the latest Tree.js (https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/Tree.js#L1792) as well as the Tree.js from 1.8 (https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.8/Tree.js#L1892).

Comment: Well, the documentation *says* it would be removed then. At the very least, it shouldn't be relied upon anymore.

Comment: Not sure what documentation you are talking about, I don't see that method mentioned in https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/releasenotes/1.7.html or https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/releasenotes/1.8.html.

The API doc (https://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_Tree__createTreeNode) does say that _createTreeNode "will probably be removed in a future release" but you can ignore that; we aren't making any significant changes to the 1.x line anymore.